# Produce a stream of values with data-driven delays in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Given an array of objects which contain a message payload and time parameter like this:

`var data = [
    { message:"Deliver me after 1000ms", time:1000 },
    { message:"Deliver me after 2000ms", time:2000 },
    { message:"Deliver me after 3000ms", time:3000 }
];`

I would like to create an observable sequence which returns the message part of each element of the array and then waits for the corresponding amount of time specified in the object. I'm open to reorganising the data structure of the array if that is necessary.

I've seen Observable.delay but can't see how it could be used with a dynamic value in this way. I'm working in RxJS 5.

Comment: Your question text says the messages should be returned (emitted?) and it should *then* wait for the corresponding amount of time, but the messages in your code suggest that wait should occur *before* this message is delivered. Which is it? And are the times from the time of subscription or the time at which the previous message was emitted?

Comment: Excuse my terminology, I'm new to RxJS. Yes I meant emitted. And I can see the confusion about the timing parameters. The accepted answer does what I want in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `delayWhen`:

```js
var data = [
    { message:"Deliver me after 1000ms", time:1000 },
    { message:"Deliver me after 2000ms", time:2000 },
    { message:"Deliver me after 3000ms", time:3000 }
];

Rx.Observable
  .from(data)
  .delayWhen(datum => Rx.Observable.timer(datum.time))
  .do(datum => console.log(datum.message))
  .subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```