# Delaying rxjs 5 Observable emission by time defined in data with scheduler

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I want to delay a Stream of data with a delay as defined in the data:

```
Rx.Observable.from([
  {message: "one", delay: 100}, 
  {message: "two", delay: 500}, 
  {message: "three", delay: 10500}
]).subscribe((e) => console.log(e.message))
```

1. It should log "one" after 100 ms, "two" after 500 ms.
2. I would like to be able to cancel the timer before the message “three” is emitted.

How would I define a rxjs 5 scheduler to accomplish that?

Comment: This is extremely broad description. You want to emit "one" at 100ms and "two" at 500ms or 100+500ms? You can cancel the emission by unsubscribing or by using operators such as `takeUntil()` or just `filter()`. So can you be more specific and describe your use-case in more detail?

Comment: I would like to schedule the emission from when the observable is activated / subscribed to. The scheduler should allow me to cancel all scheduled events _after_ the observable is activated, and events are scheduled.

Comment: So you have your own customized scheduler?

Comment: if there's no scheduler available that can handle it, yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Produce a stream of values with data-driven delays in RxJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608636/produce-a-stream-of-values-with-data-driven-delays-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on *how* you want to delay there are a few routes you can take:

### Delay the given time between each emission

Using `.concatMap` every emission will have to wait for the delayed previous emission to complete before the next:

```js
Rx.Observable.from([
  {message: "one", delay: 500}, 
  {message: "two", delay: 500}, 
  {message: "three", delay: 500}
])
.concatMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val.message).delay(val.delay))
.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

Every emission arrives after the previous has been done.

### Delay should be relative to start of stream:

Using `.mergeMap` all emissions will be started at the time they arrive and their delay will start at that time.

```js
Rx.Observable.from([
  {message: "one", delay: 500}, 
  {message: "two", delay: 500}, 
  {message: "three", delay: 500}
])
.mergeMap(val => Rx.Observable.of(val.message).delay(val.delay))
.subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

Note that all three emissions arrive at the same time.

By using standard Rx operators your cancellation support is built in. Just unsubscribe from the stream and all pending future emissions are ignored.